# shell scripting single for loop how to get a output from a file

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

Source file `data.txt`

```
A
B
.
.
.
Z
```

Source file contain A to Z write each character in one line each.

Result Need

```
A_01
A_02
.
.
.
A_26
B_01
.
.
B_26
.
.
.
Z_01
.
.
Z_26
```

Note: from the source file we need to count the no.of line and add that number to each split character.

I got a Solution But I need to do in one for statement.

```
end=`wc -l data.txt | awk '{print $1}'`

for i in $(cat data.txt )
do
  for j in `seq $end`
  do
    echo "$i"_"$j"
  done 
done
```

Comment: the tag [shell] is generic, and doesn't tell us what implementation you are using. Most likely `[bash]`, so please add a tag for your shell of preference. Search your shell's documentation for math operations. Good luck.

Comment: You can mention that `A..Z` are example values, you don't want `printf "%s\n" {A..Z}_{01..26}`.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Another nit-pick: but the use of backticks is discouraged. It's legacy, and non-POSIX. There's a number of reasons why the `$()` notation is preferred [see some here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk -v line=$(wc -l < Input_file) '{for(i=1;i<=line;i++) printf("%s_%02d\n",$0,i)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Ans is almost correct but I need is A_01...A_26...Z_01..Z_26

Comment: No. bro Same result like this showing A_1...A_26 want A_01

Comment: @ArunSolomon, Give it sometime and when you have few answers, you could select anyone of them as correct one too. I saw your profile and realize that you don't do that often, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the `wc -l` strikes me as inelegant. You can store the file in memory, or read the file twice, and solve this in pure Awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NR-FNR;i++) print $0,i}' OFS='_' file file
```

The reason this works is because `NR-FNR` is always zero for the first read of the file, while it is always 26 for the second read of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a function called `mapfile`, to read a file in an array.

```
mapfile -t data < data.txt
numbers=($(seq -f '%02.0f' "${#data[@]}"))
for line in "${data[@]}"; do
  printf "${line}_%s\n" "${numbers[@]}"
done
```